# access struct with a function, how to save the value?

Tags: c, insert, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

does anyone know how save a value into a binary tree on the left or right side?
for example we have 2 structs:

```
struct A
{
    int a;
    struct A *left;
    struct A *right;
}

struct B
{
    A *root;
}
```

and we have a function:

```
void insert(B *tree, int value)
{
    if(tree== NULL)
    {
        tree= (B*) malloc (sizeof(B));
    }
    else if(tree!=NULL)
    {
        tree->root->a = value;
        tree->root->left = NULL;
        tree->root->right = NULL;
    }
```

now we have the root...
but how to initiliase the value on the right and left side?

```
else if(tree->apointer->a< value)
{
    tree->root->left = value // with & wont work cause is a pointer to integer
}
```

does anyone know ??

Thanks in advance

Comment: Unless you're using vi on a smartphone standing up on a train, your coding style is absolutely reprehensible.

Comment: Please contact your teacher. You have a fundamental problems with some core concepts that need to be addresses in a teaching situation rather than a Q&A site.

Answer (score 0):

With `tree= (B*) malloc (sizeof(B));`, you create an object of type `B`, but you do not create an object of type `A` to which `tree->root` could point to. Accessing `tree->root->a` or the other members of `root` then is undefined behaviour;

You could write:

```
tree = malloc (sizeof(B));
tree->root = malloc(sizeof(A));
```

Comment: and how do i access the left? there is a warning when i try this:
tree->root->left = value
how can i solve this problem?

Comment: `root->left` and `root->right` both have to point to objects of type `A`; these objects usually exist when you sort in a new node. But - please don't take it negative - could it be that this example is a little bit beyond your maturity level? Binary search trees are not appropriate stuff when starting to learn C...

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no sense to discuss your code.:) Even structure definitions are written without semicolons.

Taking into account these structure definitions

```
struct A
{
    int value;
    struct A *left;
    struct A *right;
};

struct B
{
    struct A *root;
};
```

and assuming that in `main` there is the following declaration of the tree

```
int main( void )
{
    struct B tree = { NULL };
    //...
```

then the function `insert` can be defined the following way

```
int insert( struct B *tree, int value )
{
    struct A **node = &tree->root;

    while (*node)
    {
        if (value < (*node)->value)
        {
            node = &(*node)->left;
        }
        else
        {
            node = &(*node)->right;
        }
    }

    *node = malloc(sizeof(struct A));
    int success = *node != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        (*node)->value = value;
        (*node)->left = NULL;
        (*node)->right = NULL;
    }

    return success;
}
```

The function can be called like

```
insert( &tree, value );
```

or its call can be enclosed in an if statement

```
if ( insert( &tree, value ) ) { /*...*/ }
```